# How to change the text color in a listview in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my code in my edit.cs

```
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);

            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();

            _listView = new ListView();
            _listView.ItemsSource = db.Table<SpeechRecTable>().OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
            _listView.ItemSelected += _listView_ItemSelected;
            //_listView.SeparatorColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            stackLayout.Children.Add(_listView);

            _button = new Button();
            _button.Text = "UPDATE";
            _button.BackgroundColor = Color.Coral;
            _button.TextColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            _button.Clicked += _button_Clicked;
            stackLayout.Children.Add(_button);

            Content = stackLayout;
```

The default color looks like pink, and I cant find the textcolor property in the listview.

I am new in xamarin, and Im trying to create a CRUD application, I am following this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aabHAgY5VXo&t=58s

Comment: Where is your `ListView's` `ViewCell`?

Comment: To change the default color in android, go to **Android Project** > **Resources** > **Values** > **color.xml**

Comment: @FreakyAli thats the code in the tutorial, it is not an xaml.cs file, just .cs file

Comment: @AnasAlweish I found it at styles.xml, thank you for pointing that out, it was next to color.xml :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change Android accent color from Resources.

**Resources/Android/values/colors.xml**

```
<resources>
<color name="launcher_background">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

Default color is setted to pink, you can change this with a color suit with your UI color scheme. But remember that: if you change this, controls which is using accent color are also affected.

You can learn detailed information about styles and themes on Android from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#ColorPalette).